# Error for small image (<111kb) upload in CKEditor for Redmine

Tags: image, ckeditor, imagemagick, paperclip, redmine-plugins

I can upload big images above 111kb without any problem, but small images below 111kb cannot be uploaded via the "browse and upload image" function. I receive the following error:

```
Could not upload your file:

-rich_file

Paperclip:Errors::NotIdentifiedbyImageMagickError
```

I tested around 80 different images: all screenshots, all manipulated in the same software. I also tried a big image and then resized it to a small size. The big image was no problem, but again the small image gets the error.

I am using CKEditor in Redmine (Bitnami stack installation 2.6.0-3).

Let me know what information you need.

I am trying to solve the issue for a few weeks now and I have no working solution for it.

Comment: Can you post a (link to a) sample of the image showing `NotIdentifiedbyImageMagickError`? Can you also tell us, which software you sued to manipulate the screenshots? Do you have any idea, what image format the downsized screenshots use?

Comment: I use ACDSee 15 to manipulate the screenshots. All the image formats are jpeg. I can have a working big image and downsize it under 111kb and then the image does not upload any more. But I can also take a small not working image and resize it to a big size above 111kb and then it works. Here the examples [Small file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cewd44g876w1wah/youtube_small.jpg?dl=0)  [big file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8l13nt54az3r41/youtube.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Hmmm... I had a look at both files. There is nothing that looks suspicious to me in any way. Very strange bug indeed. Sorry, I think I am at the end of my wisdom here... (I could install Redmine/Bitnami 2.6.0-3 myself on some idling system, but I do not have the time for this).

Comment: Thank you for your time! Do you have an idea where I can post this problem and get some help? I am already on the Bitnami and the CKEditor Forum and try to find a solution for almost a month.